# How to show JSON in html

Tags: javascript, html, json

I want to show article authors from my API in HTML. As of now i've managed to get it to show as JSON. It looks like this:[image: JSON data]

My very simple HTML looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Test</h1>

    

</body>

<script src="../routes/news.route.js"></script>

</html>
```

My Javascript looks like this

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express();
const { executeSQL } = require("../models/database/db_connect");

router.get("/", async (req, res) => {
  let data = await executeSQL(
    "SELECT articleAuthor FROM articles"
  );
  res.send(data);
});

module.exports = router;
```

I have tried to find anything that can push me in the right direction but unfortunately i cannot find it.
Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

> You can't combine the nodejs files in the front-end html.You have request an API for author list, that gives the response of authors

Below, i am simulated the response,you can use the fetch method to call the api instead.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Author List</h1>
  <ol id='content'>
   
  </ol>
  <script>
     window.onload = async ()=>{
  const content = document.getElementById('content');
  const Responsedata = {
     "1":{
        "articleAuthor":"James,Ethen"
      },
      "2":{
        "articleAuthor":"Elisa,Ethen"
      }
   }
   /* any url the gives the response
   const data = fetch('http://localhost:3000/news').then(res=> res.json())  
   */
  const data = await new Response(JSON.stringify(Responsedata)).json();// i'm simulated here

  Object.values(data).forEach(author=>{
      const li = document.createElement('li');
      li.innerText = author.articleAuthor;
      content.append(li)
    })
}
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```